# How do I return a date value in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

For example:

```
year
-----
1999
2001
2004
2006
```

How do i return years that are greater than 2000?

Year is stored as date format.

Comment: you should read this: [functions-datetime](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 3):

Using PostgreSQL specific [DATE_PART](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year', t.date_column)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE t.date_column > DATE '2000-01-01'
```

Using EXTRACT (ANSI):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.date_column)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE t.date_column > DATE '2000-01-01'
```

You could use the function in the WHERE clause to filter out the years/etc, but doing so renders an index on the column useless.

Comment: When using the EXTRACT in the WHERE clause, a function based index on `extract(year from date_column)` would be usable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: True, didn't know PostgreSQL supported them -- do you happen to know what the first version was to support them?

Comment: The manual of 6.5 already mentions the usage of functions in the CREATE INDEX syntax. So I'd say: "always"